# yiic - php.exe is not recognized command

Tags: php, yii, cmd

I search for a lot of question here and in google also but still didnt get my answer.

i try as you can see in image, i dont know where's the error

[image]

My `PHP` path as shown in image below,

[image]

Any help please

Comment: @ArunKillu can you please elaborate, i didn't get your point

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is the path to PHP's directory in your `PATH`? If not you should add this.

In your case I believe the path you need to append will be `D:\xampp\php\`.

To update your `PATH` on Windows 7/8 you can simply right-click 'Computer', hit 'Properties', then 'Change Settings'. In the 'Advanced' tab there is an 'Environment Variables button'. Scroll the 'System Variables' until you get to `Path` and simply append the path like so:

```
;D:\xampp\php\
```

.. onto the end of the path. OK out of everything and reopen `cmd`, your command should now work.

Comment: this is my full xampp path D:\xampp\htdocs\my_sites\yii , how and where to add this path

Comment: That is not your XAMPP path, that is the path to your site. Within `D:\xampp\php` there should be a `php.exe`. I will update my answer with how to add to your `PATH`.

Comment: check my question, i upload php path image, can you please tell me where i'm wrong

Comment: Yes, you did not follow my instructions. I said to modify your `Path` variable, not add a new one.

Comment: no i did the same also, this is my path variable value **%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Autodesk\Backburner\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Autodesk Shared\;C:\PROGRA~2\Griaule\FINGER~1\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;D:\xampp\php\**

Comment: @Shams and did you restart the command prompt before trying again?

Comment: @Shams Not a problem, glad it's sorted.

Answer (score 1):

```
I also faced the same problem. 
Error :- Path of the file is not set properly.
Step 1: Go to CMD.
Step 2: Then reach to your desired folder .For Ex:- cd c:/xampp/htdocs/yii/framework
Step 3: In CMD -> path C:\xampp\htdocs\yii\framework ; C:\xampp\php
Step 4: In CMD -> path  
Step 5: Now Execute your desired command for yii in cmd -> yiic webapp yii_test
Work Done!
```